# mysql query needed

Tags: mysql

not a programmer so  need help with this one I am using Wordpress 3.0.2 and wp-calendar
i hav looked at the mysql data base  in PhpMyAdmin under
 wordpress   -   wp_calendar_categories  - There is categories 0 -4 (5)

i wish to out put this data to a page in wordpress in the following format:-

for category 1 which is also in category 4 data output Title- date -time -location
for category 2 which is also in category 4 data output Title- date -time -location
for category 3 which is also in category 4 data output Title- date -time -location
using the commands with the wp-calendar plugin will not give me a output of cat1 in cat4 
i can produce a list of all in each category in the following format Title - date - time- location

os any sql masters out there please help can give more info if required

THANKS

Comment: You might get a better answer here:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to output information that is in multiple categories.  For this you want a join.

```
SELECT title, date, time, location
FROM wp_calendar_categories c1
JOIN wp_calendar_categories c4
    ON c1.title = c4.title
    AND c1.date = c4.date
    AND c1.time = c4.time
    AND c1.location = c4.location
WHERE c1.category = 1
    AND c4.category = 4
```

You can combine results (provided the columns are the same) using a union

```
SELECT title, date, time, location
....
UNION
SELECT title, date, time, location
```

I would advise searching on the web for SQL tutorials to help get you started.

Comment: Thank you  all the data field area the same each categry has a title, startDate, enddate, start time, end time, location the information will be the same if in both categories so i think your solution will help as a newbie and still learning any and all help is apreciated thanks will try sql tutorials for more knowledge